# How to open a directory without knowing where is located

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I open a directory in linux without knowing where is located? I want to open it in a script, but I can't use cd myDirectory because i dont know where it is (and it is not in the current directory). 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: what do you mean by "opening a directory". Wanna point to it inside the script?

Comment: This might be an XY problem. What are you trying to do? Why do you need to "open" a directory you don't even know exists?

Comment: Let's say we have aDirectory somewhere. I want to open it, but i don't know where is located. How can i do that? It exists 100%.

Comment: scan the entire filesystem until you find it? this works unless you have duplicate names

Comment: I have to do that in a script.

Comment: you can scan the filesystem in bash. Are we talking about *unix right?

Comment: I dont really get it. How can i scan the filesystem in a script? What's the command? And moreover, how can i use the output of the scanning?

Comment: What do you mean "open" a directory? I don't know what that means. Please elaborate, and don't just restate your question using the same words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find /location/to/search -type d -name "directoryName" -print > /file/to/save/found/directory/paths.txt
```

Explanation:

- `-type d`: match only directories,
- `-name "directoryName"`: match directories with the specified name only; accepts `*` wildcard,
- `-print`: prints each found path,
- `> /file/to/save/found/directory/paths.txt` redirection of output to file `/file/to/save/found/directory/paths.txt`

To use it in a script, you could loop through the matches:

```
while read -r line; do
    echo "$line contains $(ls -F $line | wc -l) files"
done < <(find /location/to/search -type d -name "directoryName" -print)
```